# How to request popup-auth-window on open google-spreadsheet to get user e-mail?

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, oauth, popupwindow

I tryed to get email (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()), but i should to ask user permission:

```
// it script on google script 
function onOpen() {
Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
Logger.log(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail())
}
// it's manifest for access
{
"timeZone": "Europe/Moscow",
"dependencies": {
},
"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
"oauthScopes": [
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp"
]
}
```

How I should to request auth-window?

Comment: From GAS documentation on the getEmail() method of class 'User': "If security policies do not allow access to the user's email address, this method returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user)"

Comment: Bottom line is, you can't run any scripts, including simple trigger functions like onOpen, without user's permission.

Comment: How to get user permission? When I start my function from script-view, I saw request to auth %)

Comment: That's because it's your script that you manually executed 'as you'. You can't trigger code executions on behalf of other users without their consent. If you want to share your script, the only way to do so is building a Google Sheets add-on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#add-ons_for_google_sheets Add-ons are subject to review and approval by Google, so I doubt they'll approve any script collecting users' email addresses, even considering the inherent limitations of the 'getEmail()' method described above

Comment: Put up a `Browser.msgBox(`[`url`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getAuthorizationInfo(AuthMode))`)` onOpen asking for authorization.

Comment: If you want to give someone else your script you can share full access with them on a team drive.   Make sure the script is only accessibe by you the owner and copy it to the team drive when they take it off on the other side it's now there's.